# Change icon color of the div after the first one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what I have: **the div will change the color after click.**

what I want to do: **the first click will change the background ( I did ) , but the second click will change just the icon color of other div.**

**so if I click in any div**

**first** will change the background color ( I did )

**second** if I click in any other one will change the icon color.

as well I would like after the second click, show me a alert saying 'you can just select 2 div at the time'

I am very brand new in js and jquery and that was the max I could do.

**html:**

```
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $box = $('.box').mousedown(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight')
        $box.on('mouseenter.highlight', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        $box.off('mouseenter.highlight')
    })
});
```

**css:**

```
.box {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.highlight {
    background: #0000FF;
}

.fa-trash {
  color:red;
}

.fa-trash{
  color:green;
}
```

that is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/wv4f2hda/4/

Comment: what does icon color means in this?

Comment: I used a Trash for sample but will be other icon, will means a document is getting compared understood the logic? :) , thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .box {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.highlight {
    background: #0000FF;
}

.fa-trash {
  color:red;
}

.fa-trash{
  color:green;
}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flag = false;
    var $box = $('.box').mousedown(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
        if(flag) $('.fa-trash').css('color' , 'black');
        flag =  $(this).hasClass('highlight')
        $box.on('mouseenter.highlight', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        $box.off('mouseenter.highlight')
    })
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Try this

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the only icon who suppose change color is the one was clicked, right now is changing in all.  the background color supose not change just the icon color of the clicked icon, As well I would like a message after the second click saying the person can't click anymore blocking the clicks till they deselect the divs selected. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script, just make a flag with true and false, probably solve your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var click = false;
    $(document).on('click', '.box', function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
       $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        click = false;
        return false;
      }
     if(!click){
       $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
         click = true;
      }else{
       $(this).find("i").toggleClass('red');
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.highlight {
    background: #0000FF;
}

.fa-trash.red {
  color:red;
}

.fa-trash{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
<div class="box"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i></div>
```

Comment: nice is what I am looking for :), thank you, but how can I do after the second click when turn the icon to red appear a message saying you cant select more than 2? will be possible?